# add a column with data to table in mysql

Tags: mysql

Now that I want to add a new column with the data already to an existing table in SQL, what should I do.

Say I have a table temp with column (id, price, quantity) with data look like this:

```
id   price   quantity
01     3     4
02     8     2
03     9     1
```

and now I want to a derived column call revenue using the code:

```
select id, price * quantity as revenue
from temp;
```

the result should look like this:

```
id   revenue
01     12
02     16
03     9
```

Now I want to add this revenue into the temp table with existing data here

I have tried alter table with 'as' but it doesn't work, and also I have tried to create a new table with revenue, create a new column in the table then using 'update' will give me something like this:

```
 id   price   quantity revenue
 01     3     4
 02     8     2
 03     9     1
 null  null null        12
 null  null null        16
 null  null null        9
```

what should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend *not* actually adding a new column to your table for the revenue, since it is just derived from other columns.  Instead, consider creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW temp_revenue AS
SELECT id, price * quantity AS revenue
FROM temp;
```

If you are using the NDB storage engine, then you could also take advantage of computed columns, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    price DECIMAL(13,2) NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    revenue DECIMAL(13, 2) AS price * quantity,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But, this would not be an option for you if you are using MyISAM or InnoDB.

Comment: @W.Yan Maybe you do not have permissions to create views.  Can you create temp tables?  This would be an alternative.

Comment: I could create the table, but is there another way that do this after the table was created?

Comment: Yes, just select `price * quantity` when you query.  That's probably the easiest thing to do, actually.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

```
ALTER TABLE temp ADD COLUMN revenue INT AFTER quantity;
UPDATE temp SET revenue = price * quantity;
```

This will add the new column, then update every row's `revenue` column value with the computed `price * quantity` of each row.

Comment: Is there any possible way by using subquery to do this in one step?

Comment: @W.Yan - no, the DDL statement and the DML statement cannot be combined.  Also, depending on your use case, you could look into [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).